# Buffer Failure in C

Tags: c

I am try to write a buffer so I can remove a lot of null "00" characters in a file.  The characters are useless and are completely random.  They are wreaking havoc on the searcher in the program.  The code below compiles but just seems to hang when a file is passed to it.  Any suggestions will be helpful.

```
void ReadFile(char *name)
{
    FILE *dbg;
    char *buffer;
    unsigned long fileLen;

    //Open file
    dbg = fopen(dbg, "w+");
    if (!dbg)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", name);
        return;
    }

    //Get file length
    fseek(dbg, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen = ftell(dbg);
    fseek(dbg, 0, SEEK_SET);

    //Allocate memory
    buffer = (char *)malloc(fileLen+1);
    if (!buffer)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
        fclose(dbg);
        return;
    }

    //Read file contents into buffer
    fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, dbg);
    for(i = fileLen-1; i >= 0 && buffer[i] == 0; i--);  
    i++;
    if (i > 0)
    {
        fwrite(buffer, 1, i, dbg);
    }
    fclose(dbg);

    //Do what ever with buffer

    free(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
dbg = fopen(dbg, "w+");
```

to

```
dbg = fopen(name, "w+");
```

Also, if you want to read the file, change it then write it, you shouldn't open it with `"w+"`. You should first open the file with `"r"`, read from it, do whatever change you want, then `fclose` it, then again open it but this time with `"w"` so that you write over it. After you have opened it in `"w"`rite mode, you can write the modified buffer back into the file.

Answer (score 2):

You opened a file for writing and then you try to read from it.

Check the return value of `fread` and all the other calls.